# How to add a file to the home directories of all existing and future users

Tags: puppet

I'm starting to use puppet to manage a couple of servers and I'm not sure how to achieve the following.

I've got a `users` module which I use to create common users across all servers. I've got a `git` module which I use to install git and set up a system-wide config in `/etc/gitconfig`. What I'd like to do is:

1. On servers which are configured to install git (not all of them), go and drop a (templated) `.gitconfig` into the home directories of *all existing users*. And obviously manage this for changes to the template.
2. Add the `.gitconfig` for all future users. But I don't feel this belongs in the `users` module - I think it belongs in the `git` module. It feels like I want to know when any user has been added (not just a given instance of user), and then be able to access the parameters of that user creation (e.g. home directory, real name and username).

Essentially, part 2 would be easy if I just deployed a templated `.gitconfig` to all users created by the `users` module. But I don't really want users to have a `.gitconfig` file if git isn't installed on the system. So what I'm really trying to say is "for all managed users on this system, if git is installed, manage a `.gitconfig` file".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yo will need to use two procedures , first for already created accounts :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-shell-batch-copy.html

and another one for future users  :

http://linuxers.org/howto/how-set-default-content-new-users-home-directory-using-etcskel

Comment: Well, I could build the whole management using shell scripts! I was hoping to leverage the power of Puppet to achieve something simple here. Regarding /etc/skel, I need to be able to template the .gitconfig on various details of the user being created (e.g. username, etc.) so this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be easier if users and nodes that need to have git are managed by puppet:

```
class git {
  packakge { "git":
    ensure => installed,
  }
}

class users {
  user { ... }
  file { "/home/${user}/.gitconfig":
    ensure => present,
    content => template("gitconfig"),
    require => Class["git"],
  }
}
```

Then for each git node, include class git.

Comment: I'm still new to puppet, but my reading of this is that as soon as I start to use that class to manage users, my servers will all get git installed on them due to the `require` meta-attribute. This is not what I want. I want to pick and choose which servers get git, and only manage the .gitconfig file for managed users on servers where I have chosen to also install git.

Comment: Well, it was just an example. You can subclass your users so that you have sysadmin users, git users, dba users, etc.

Comment: I know. But none of that really relates to the actual question, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you really want to detect if git is on a machine, you'll have to write your own facts for facter which is a chapter of a book on its own. You may want to get a copy of [Pro Puppet](http://www.apress.com/9781430230571) which is on sale at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

> for all managed users on this system,

So you either have to define this on the users module, or export a [virtual resource](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/virtual_resources.html) from it. Given the usage, I don't see a way to do it with virtual resources.

> if git is installed,

Strictly speaking, create a [custom fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) to check if it is installed. For example:

```
# git.rb
Facter.add("git") do
        setcode do
                %x{/usr/bin/test -x /usr/bin/git && /bin/echo yes || /bin/echo no}.chomp
        end
end
```

On the other hand, the `git` module could export a virtual resource, such as the `.gitconfig` file, and the user module could realize it. I don't think it is possible to realize the same resource in a parameterized (user's home directory) way.

> manage a .gitconfig file

Well, that you know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just ensure a base file, use tags.  The virtual file resource will only get realized if the git class has been included.  You could set this up with a template to add in the user name and email.  This can cause problems if users want to customize their git config though (puppet will overwrite their changes).

```
class git {
   @file { 'git_user_config':
     tag     => 'git_user_config',
     path    => '/tmp/.gitconfig',
     content => template("git/gitconfig.erb"),
     require => Package["git"],
  }
}

class user {
  # user defs here

  File <| tag == 'git_user_config' |> {
    path => "/home/${user}/.gitconfig",
  }
}
```

You may also be able to leverage the puppet-stdlib (https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) getparam feature.

Untested code, not sure if this would work.  Generally I like the tagged virtual resources a lot.

```
class users {
  user {...}

  if ( (defined(Package['git']) && (getparam(Package['git'],'ensure') == 'present') ) {
    file {
      "/home/${user}/.gitconfig":
        ensure => present,
        content => template("git/gitconfig.erb"),
        require => Class["git"],
    }
  }
```